# How to set up a request header for an Authenticated API GET request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-2.x

I'm trying to make an authenticated GET request to an API. This is one of my first attempts working with Python's `request` library. I've looked over similar posts to this one, but they're a bit too generic to answer my question, it seems. Their answers work for nearly every other case I've worked with, so it feel a bit stuck.

The request header is fairly lengthy:

```
':authority': 'api-WEBSITE.com',
':method': 'GET',
':path': 'ENDPOINT',
':scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'application/json',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'authorization': 'AUTH_TOKEN', 
'content-type': 'application/json',
'cookie': 'VERY_LONG_COOKIE',
'origin': 'https://WEBSITE.com',
'referer': 'https://WEBSITE.com/app',
'user-agent': 'LIST_OF_BROWSERS'
```

My code that makes this request:

```
import requests

requestURL = "https://api-WEBSITE.com/ENDPOINT"

parameters = {
    ':authority': 'api-WEBSITE.com',
    ':method': 'GET',
    ':path': 'ENDPOINT',
    ':scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'authorization': 'AUTH_TOKEN', 
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': 'VERY_LONG_COOKIE',
    'origin': 'https://WEBSITE.com',
    'referer': 'https://WEBSITE.com/app',
    'user-agent': 'LIST_OF_BROWSERS'
}

response = requests.get(requestURL, parameters)

print(response.status_code)
```

When I run this, I'm getting a 401 status code asking for authentication; however, I can't seem to find out what's throwing this 401 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To supply headers for a python request: you must do this 
r = requests.get(url, headers = headersDict)

Where headersDict is a valid dictionary of the headers you want added to the request